# Transparent ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, proxy, iptables, ssh-tunnel, reverse-proxy

I have an SSH tunnel defined in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.  It contains:

```
LocalForward 0.0.0.0:8000 some-service:80
LocalForward 0.0.0.0:8001 some-other-service:80
```

I would still like to be able to access the tunnels via their original DNS names (e.g. `curl some-service` should still work, rather than having to use `curl 0.0.0.0:8000`)

In an attempt to do this I added the following to my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.2 some-service
127.0.0.3 some-other-service
```

Now, I think, I need some `iptables` commands which will do the following:

```
When I see a request to 127.0.0.2:80 I should proxy it to 127.0.0.1:8000
When I see a request to 127.0.0.3:80 I should proxy it to 127.0.0.0:8001
```

Such that, `curl some-service` would resolve to `127.0.0.2` (via `/etc/hosts`, which would in turn be proxied to `127.0.0.1:8000` (via `iptables`), which in turn hit `some-service:80` (via the ssh tunnel)

---

Question: I feel like there should be an easier way to achieve this?  If not, what would the `iptables` commands look like?

Comment: Please delete this, otherwise a moderator will likely remove it since it's already been flagged 10x as a duplicate.  Since StackExchange sites are answer sites, double-posting creates clutter, among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure the correct etiquette here (close the question? mark as duplicate?) but I have an accepted answer for this question here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/982063/transparent-ssh-tunneling

Comment: I think the etiquette is not to ask the same question on different stackexchange sites. If it was my question, I'd delete this one.

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ssh` [*DynamicForward*](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#DynamicForward) option to set up a socks proxy, by adding this to your `.ssh/config`:

```
DynamicForward localhost:8000
```

Then tell curl to use SOCKS:

```
curl --socks5 localhost:8000 ...
```

There are other ways to make `curl` use SOCKS; refer to the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl).

Comment: Hey, might be missing something - not sure how that helps?